# Ideas for bundling dll assets without installing referenced modules

Tags: webpack, codesandbox

So we are working on a site generator using React and Webpack. The tool comes with a designer which lets you add third party npm plugins and use them in the React code snippets.

The end-user can make changes to various site templates and then the tool compiles the site bundle on our servers using webpack and deploys them on a cloud host selected by the user. It is also possible for the user to preview the site changes on our servers before deploying it.

So far our strategy was to generate a package.json and webpack.config file for every site and then run webpack. This works but is very slow. Now our plan is to use `DllPlugin` and `DllReferencePlugin` to pre-create dll scripts for those packages which we add to the baseline package.json of the site template code. This should cut short the site build time drastically, per our experiments.

However, there's one other scenario where this strategy fails... An end-user can add npm packages of her choice to her site and reference them in the site's code. We currently have to perform two steps with user packages -

1. We need to `yarn install` the packages (of-course!).
2. We need to bundle all of them into a dll so subsequent builds are fast.

We have noticed that most of the time is spent in #1, sometimes several minutes as yarn installs packages. Then it takes some more time to finish #2. We have been experimenting with reducing #2 by using our own instance of [webpack-dll](https://github.com/cerebral/webpack-dll) service to offload dll generation to it and download the manifest to the site's webpack setup. This also has the benefit of reusing cached results for new requests.

So in theory, we don't need to install user packages because they have been pre-bundled in the dll, thereby saving us a lot of time in the bundling phase.
However, with some experiments with the way DllPlugin and DllReferencePlugin work, it is apparent that even when we have a manifest and dll file for the packages, webpack wont bundle them unless they are installed.

My guess is that as the dll bundles don't store entry point information of the bundled packages, webpack must parse the installed package's `package.json` file, look for `main` (or the other entry-points), then check if they are in the dll manifest or not. Essentially this means that the pre-bundled packages must also be installed first.

So I invite the webpack gurus to provide some guidance. We have also looked into other approaches like the client side bundling of [codesandbox](https://github.com/CompuIves/codesandbox-client) which is very clever, but doesn't fit in our server based build process.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting issue and can be solved in a lot of different ways, each with their tradeoffs.

The dll service we use (webpack-dll-prod.herokuapp.com) with CodeSandbox is also used by WebpackBin, which uses it on the server side (with the dll plugin). You can find the source here: https://github.com/christianalfoni/webpack-bin. The disadvantage of the webpack-dll approach is that we add all *possible* entries manually, which can make bundles very big and in some rare cases impossible to bundle.

I'm writing a Medium post about different ways to approach this issue, it's not done yet, but you can see the draft here: https://medium.com/@ives.v.h/how-we-make-npm-packages-work-in-the-browser-6ce16aa4cee6. Maybe it provides some inspiration in how to approach this.

Comment: Thanks @Ives! Do you think it'd be possible to use the `externals` information which webpack-dll-service produces, to make webpack aware of the entries, via a plugin? Currently sandbox makes use of that information on the client side. I haven't written any webpack plugins so far to comment on the possibility of such a plugin.

Comment: I believe you can just pass the manifest in a DllReferencePlugin, like here: https://github.com/christianalfoni/webpack-bin/blob/97c9dfe0f6cddba69b85ae4b0b7d03b5dc82ab4e/server/sessionBundler.js#L22-L27. We added the externals information specifically for CodeSandbox, so DllReferencePlugin doesn't even need that.

Comment: Yes, we are doing that, but webpack is not able to find entry points if the bundled packages are not installed. It works like any other dll bundle once you install the bundled packages.